# Why does VSCode not show PHP errors/warnings etc in the Debug Console

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

When debugging PHP in VSCode the errors/warnings etc and output are not displayed in the Debug Console when using the "Listen for Xdebug" configuration.

It does work if I use the "Launch currently open script" profile but this is no good as I need to initiate the debug from a browser as it's a web application.

Simple example below:

This screen grab is using "Launch currently open script" where the warning is showed in the console:

[image: debug with warning message]

This is when it's triggered from a browser using "Listen for Xdebug". The Debug Console is empty.

[image: debug with no messages]

Using:

- Latest version of VSCode (1.69.2) - have tried various Xdebug extensions, all have the same behaviour
- Xdebug 3.2
- PHP-FPM 8.2

I have come from using a very old Zend Debugger IDE and would really like to start using VSCode but this is holding me back.